# Does Spring MVC issue a commit after calling SpringStoredProcedure.execute()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, struts

Does Spring issue a commit to the database after each package call, or does it only commit after everything is done?

I am using Spring and Struts. In my controller class, I am calling many database packages with spring stored procedure in a DAO class. each call has its only method in the DAO class

My question is, will Spring commit only after all calls have been made from the controller class and the controller has finished, or will it commit after each execution of a `SpringStoredProcedure`?

```
my_package_getusers = SpringStoredProcedure.getStoredProcedureCompiled(getJdbcTemplate()
....
my_package_getusers.execute(params).get("result")
```

Comment: What library is this class from?

Answer (score 2):

Spring utility classes from spring-jdbc don't make any commits. The responsibility for commiting transaction belongs to the spring-tx (transaction support.

This is usually made by placing `@Transactional` annotation on the method that should be run in transaction scope. So if you have method

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(SomeClass arg) {...}
```

entering that method will create new transaction, and that transaction will be commited after leaving the transaction, if the transactional context doesn't exist. However, if that method is called from other method annotated with `@Transactional`, the parent transaction context will be used.

As alternative, you can use `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate` to gain more control over transactions (for example, launching separate transaction from transactional context).

Example:

```
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
         // do something in trancation)
        }
    });
```

Note, that on some databases, such as Oracle, you can commit transaction within stored procedure, which will persist all changes made in existing transaction, and the new transaction will follow.